# entering when tk_messageBox appear in tcl

Tags: unit-testing, tcl, tk-toolkit, keystroke

so i am trying to do some unit test in the tcl gui , in some part of the unit test , there is a tk_messageBox that will pop up and if i dont press enter , the unit test wont continue

do anyone of you guys know how to replicate the enter button(keystroke)? or better yet, a command to inject into tk_messageBox to make it go away

tried the invoke command but the tk_messageBox  does not have any name

```
tk_messageBox -icon error -title TEST -message "this is a test tkbox" -type ok -parent .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what platform you're on. If you're on Unix, you can do:

```
# Widget name depends on what is the parent widget and message box type
# This is correct for -parent . -type ok
.__tk__messagebox.ok invoke
```

This won't work on Windows or OSX, because those two platforms use the native system dialogs. If you're there, you'll need to adjust the code to not put up a message box dialog in the first place *or* ask a generic automation tool to click the button for you.

Comment: hi , this would be the comment that i am looking for. i cant really find it anywhere thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need to test Tk's tk_messageBox, you can just skip that portion of the code.  Set a variable in your test unit:

```
set ::_testmode true
```

In your code:

```
if { ! [info exists ::_testmode] } {
    tk_messageBox ...
} else {
  # if you are using the return code from tk_messageBox, you
  # can set it here.
}
```

Of course, this makes the source code a bit messier, but the tests will work.   I had to do similar if-blocks around tk_getSaveFile and tk_getOpenFile, as similarly to what Donal has pointed out for tk_messageBox, these cannot be easily skipped on Windows and Mac OS X.

Comment: hi thanks for the input but using this method would mean changing thousand of lines of code for the unit test which would make it un-efficient but thanks :)

Comment: That might be a bit much, yes.   If you are on windows, then I would look into the "autohotkey" program -- it may be able to automate some of these tasks for you.